# How to know which process will be fired by a certain file in c#

Tags: c#, file, process, io

I would like to know which process will be fired before a file is started with:

```
Process.Start("PathToFile");
```

Then I would like to have the path to the process.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to know it before/without starting the process?

Comment: Are you specifying the actual path ("%systemroot%\system32"), or a pathless program name like "notepad.exe"?

Comment: Are you trying to run a program like notepad?  Or are you trying to open a document, like recipes.doc?

Comment: @agent-j  .doc, .docx and .pdf

Comment: The only solution I can thing of is reading the registry entries and imitating the shell logic. This is obviously evil.

Comment: I misunderstood the question at first, but my answer is now updated with some very rudimentary code to lookup the command the shell will execute from the registry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at the `MainModule` property of the Process returned from [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx):

```
Process p = Process.Start(@"D:\\test.txt");
string executableStarted = p.MainModule.FileName; // full path to notepad.exe
```

However, you should remember that the return value from Proces.Start might be null - according to MSDN, the return value is:

> A new Process component that is
>   associated with the process resource,
>   or null, if no process resource is
>   started (for example, if an existing
>   process is reused).

## Update

In order to know the executable *prior to launching the process*, you will have to look under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT in the registry. This would be the code for going from a file name to the command the shell will execute when opening the file:

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
var regClasses = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot;
var extensionKey = regClasses.OpenSubKey(extension);
var typeKey = extensionKey.GetValue(String.Empty); 
var cmdKey = regClasses.OpenSubKey(typeKey + @"\shell\open\command");
string command = cmdKey.GetValue(null) as string;
```

Comment: Evil, but I can't think of anything better.

Comment: Thank you. I think your answer should work in most case. But in my situation, the registry does not reflect exactly what Process.Start() will start. I've installed Office word 2010 on my computer, then I installed Word 2007 to test something. In the registry, .doc and docx are supposed to be opened with word 2007, but it opens with word 2010... really weird. But you definitely deserve more reputation for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

<del>It returns a Process object containing more information. MainModule might be the right property for you.</del>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainmodule(v=VS.80).aspx

**EDIT:**

> Do you want to know it before/without
>   starting the process? -Yes

You could lookup the registered file handler in the registry - for .doc, .txt, etc.

Answer (score 0):

### Documents that you want to use the windows file association to open

I found this link here that explains how to create a file association.  [This may help.](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/70263.aspx)  Of course you'll need to read the registry.  There are two formats that I know of.

### Programs to which you don't know the path

The path environment variable is consulted after the current directory as default paths to look in when the path is not provided.
The Path environment variable can help you here.

```
  public static string GetPath (string pathToFile)
  {
     string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(pathToFile);
     List<string> folders = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path").Split(';').ToList ();
     folders.Insert(0, Environment.CurrentDirectory);
     foreach (string folder in folders)
     {
        string fileName;
        try
        {
           // Can't trust that the Path environment variable is constructed correctly.
           fileName = Path.Combine(folder, fileNameOnly);
        }
        catch
        {
           continue;
        }
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
           return fileName;
     }
     return null;
  }
```

Edit: Added link to [MS: path](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/path.mspx?mfr=true).
Edit: Added another [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749986.aspx).

Comment: @Jean, Sorry.  I wrote this code before I understood that you were opening files.  I thought you were trying to run a program that you didn't know the path to.

Comment: @Jean, I don't know a silver bullet for this one.  I added a link that you should look at.